# Test for new id combinations in R

Tags: c++, r, matrix, dplyr, tidyverse

I am looking to create an indicator that checks whether the a group takes new combinations of numbers or not. I have a dataset like this one:

```
combinations <- data.frame(combination_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                 2, 2, 2, 
                                 3,
                                 4, 
                                 5, 5, 5, 5,
                                 6, 6, 6),

                    number = c(20, 10, 12, 18,
                                20, 10, 12,
                                20,
                                40,
                                20, 10, 30, 18,
                                18, 30, 10))
```

What I want is the following:

```
dataset_2 <- data.frame(combination_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                 2, 2, 2, 
                                 3,
                                 4, 
                                 5, 5, 5, 5,
                                 6, 6, 6),

                    number = c(20, 10, 12, 18,
                                20, 10, 12,
                                20,
                                40,
                                20, 10, 30, 18,
                                18, 30, 10),
                  new_combination = c(1, 1, 1, 1,
                                      0,0,0,
                                      0,
                                      1,
                                      1,1, 1, 1,
                                      0, 0, 0))
```

Basically an indicator new_combination that is 1 if any of the possible combinations in that combination_id is new (i.e. not present in the lower values of combination_id) or if it is just one number that has not been seen, and is zero if a number is alone but has been seen before (as 20 in group 3) or if all combinations have been seen before (as in groups 2 and 6).
So the first group takes value of 1 because none of those numbers or combinations have been taken before, group 2 takes the value of 0 because all possible combinations are also in group 1, group 3 is only one number that has been seen before so takes the value of 0. Group 4 has a new number (40) so takes the value of 1. Group 5 has new combinations with the number 30 so takes the value of 1 and group 6 has no new combinations so takes the value of zero.

I hope this made it clear what I am looking for.
Any ideas? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dplyr` approach:

```r
require(dplyr)
combinations %>% dplyr::mutate(new_combination = !duplicated(number)) %>%
                 group_by(combination_id) %>%
                 dplyr::mutate(new_combination = as.numeric(any(new_combination))) %>%
                 ungroup()

   combination_id number new_combination
            <dbl>  <dbl>           <dbl>
 1              1     20               1
 2              1     10               1
 3              1     12               1
 4              1     18               1
 5              2     20               0
 6              2     10               0
 7              2     12               0
 8              3     20               0
 9              4     40               1
10              5     20               1
11              5     10               1
12              5     30               1
13              5     18               1
14              6     18               0
15              6     30               0
16              6     10               0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(data.table) 
setDT(combinations)
combinations[, new_combinations := ifelse(
  combination_id %in% combinations[rowid(number) == 1, combination_id], 1, 0)]
#    combination_id number new_combinations
# 1:              1     20                1
# 2:              1     10                1
# 3:              1     12                1
# 4:              1     18                1
# 5:              2     20                0
# 6:              2     10                0
# 7:              2     12                0
# 8:              3     20                0
# 9:              4     40                1
#10:              5     20                1
#11:              5     10                1
#12:              5     30                1
#13:              5     18                1
#14:              6     18                0
#15:              6     30                0
#16:              6     10                0
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option with `ave` + `duplicated`

```
transform(
  combinations,
  new_combination = ave(+!duplicated(number), combination_id, FUN = max)
)
```

gives

```
   combination_id number new_combination
1               1     20               1
2               1     10               1
3               1     12               1
4               1     18               1
5               2     20               0
6               2     10               0
7               2     12               0
8               3     20               0
9               4     40               1
10              5     20               1
11              5     10               1
12              5     30               1
13              5     18               1
14              6     18               0
15              6     30               0
16              6     10               0
```